# Securing a PHP config file

Tags: php, config

How can I secure my config file in PHP to prevent unauthorized access or modification? Should I store the file outside of the web root, or use file permissions to restrict access?

I'm trying to secure a PHP config file that I'm including in my application using the include statement ( include 'config.php'). I'm not sure whether I should store the file outside of the web root or use file permissions to restrict access. I've tried searching online for best practices, but I'm not sure which approach to take. I expected to find a clear answer, but I'm still unsure about what to do. Can anyone provide guidance on how to secure an included PHP config file and prevent unauthorized access or modification?

Comment: Storing it outside of the document root, will prevent it from being _directly_ requestable via HTTP. That will make no difference as long as everything on your server works as it should - everything inside of `<?php ... ?>` tags will be parsed, and only any potential output would be returned to the client. Should however for some reason sending those files through the PHP parser fail at some point, the web server might return the actual file contents directly. If the file is not accessible via HTTP because it was placed outside the doc root, then _that_ potential issue can not arise.

Comment: Store outside web root, make it have `775` as permissions, have it .gitignore if using git so that the values in it aren't available in your git repo for accessing.

Answer (score 0):

For app secret you can use a vault store. Example https://www.twilio.com/blog/manage-application-secrets-with-php-using-vault